# Is there a way to do something similar to IIF(condition, trueValue, falseValue) within a linq statement?

Tags: vb.net, linq, ternary-operator

I am trying to return a string if a property is null in my linq entity framework query when pulling from the database.

```
select new with { .StringOnlyProp = IIF(x.PossiblyNull Is Nothing, "", x.PossiblyNull)
```

This throws an error stating that linq cant interpret IIF.

I believe c# syntax is similar to x.PossiblyNull ?? ""

I am hoping VB.NET has something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a general case you can have:

```
value = If(<test>, <true result>, <false result>);
```

this is similar to what you already have, except that IIF evaluates both return values (which is an easy source of bugs). It is the vb.net equivalent of the following:

```
value = <test> ? <true result> : <false result>;
```

For the shortcut version of a null test you have the null-coalescing operator:

```
value = If(PossiblyNull,<result if null>)
```

This is the vb.net version of:

```
value = <test> ?? <result if null>;
```

Watch out though - depending on what you're doing with your linq you may still have problems if the linq cannot be converted to a database query.

Comment: I don't know how I've been writing vb.net for 7 years and never came across this. Thanks, ill try it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the VB equivalent of C#s `??` operator is [`If`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx). For example, you just need to remove a single letter form your example:

```
If(x.PossiblyNull Is Nothing, "", x.PossiblyNull)
```

Or as pointed out by @Glorin in the comments, use the [two argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx#Anchor_3) version of the `If` function for null coalescing:

```
If(x.PossiblyNull Is Nothing, "")
```

Comment: You can generally simplify `If` for null coalescing to `If(x.PossiblyNull, "")`

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Good spot, this is why I stick to C# usually :)